# Integral of $f(\alpha , \beta, x)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $tanx = 2x$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I am looking for alternate approaches to this question.

Here's the question:

> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be positive distinct roots of the equation $tanx = 2x$, then evaluate:$$\int_0^1 sin(\alpha x)sin(\beta x)\,dx$$

The way I did it was:

Write both sine terms in Euler's form and then expand the product.

Collect the terms to form $cos((\alpha +\beta )x)$ and $cos((\alpha -\beta )x)$ terms .

$$ = \frac{-1}{2}\int_0^1 cos((\alpha +\beta )x) - cos((\alpha -\beta )x) \,dx $$

Now integrate :

$$=\frac{-1}{2} \left[ \frac{sin((\alpha +\beta )x)}{(\alpha +\beta )} - \frac{sin((\alpha -\beta )x)}{(\alpha -\beta )} \right]_0^1$$

Put in limits and convert $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in denominator to $\frac{tan\alpha}{2} \ and \ \frac{tan\beta}{2}$ using the equation given.

Then through quite rigorous trigonometry, the result is $0$.

I am interested in knowing alternate approaches to this problem, preferably a quicker approach.

Thanks

Comment: You can first show that after you substitute $x = 1$ into the antiderivative, you get
$$\frac
 {\beta \sin \alpha \cos \beta - \alpha \cos \alpha \sin \beta}
 {\alpha^2 - \beta^2}$$
(the conditions ensure that $\alpha^2 - \beta^2 \neq 0$). Then divide by $\cos \alpha \cos \beta$.